# Mysql 5.7.9 JSON type with Doctrine DQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

anybody try to work with doctrine dql and MySQL JSON type?

I trying to build equal sql

```
SELECT o0_.id AS id_0, ..., o0_.json AS json_6 
FROM ...  
ORDER BY o0_.json->"$.index" DESC LIMIT 10;
```

I mean this part:

```
ORDER BY o0_.json->"$.index" DESC
```

For that i wrote this code

```
// MySQL 5.7.9 JSON features
$queryBuilder->addOrderBy('o.json->"$.' . $column . '"', mb_strtolower($value) == 'desc' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC');
```

and get exception

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 210: Error: Expected Literal, got '>'
```

Anybody have ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: My guess is you'll need an updated version of Doctrine when it starts fully supporting this feature as it does not seem to fully support it yet.

Comment: I am pretty sure as well that this isn't supported and I doubt it'll be supported soon. You'll have to load the full json field by your query and to your filter/ordering based on your (hydrated) result.

Comment: DQL ≠ SQL: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html